# AES encryption of File using JFileChooser

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I have been working on this method for longer than i would like to admit and its becoming increasingly difficult to scan this over and over I clearly don't know what the problem is hence why I am posting.

**OBJECTIVE**: select file, encrypt file, upload file to server
**PROBLEM:** lack of knowledge and resources out of ideas. Error exceptions '  java.lang.NullPointerException'

Im sure its something simple and the crypto guys know exactly whats going on if you would kindly offer your input so that I can learn and put the blocks together so to speak it would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
 private byte[] getKeyBytes(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(key.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }

    public Cipher getCipherEncrypt(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }


// Working Upload Method To DropBox Cloud
public void uploadFile () throws DbxException, IOException, FileLoadException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidParameterSpecException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException, ShortBufferException, Exception {

// autheticate if there is a accessToken here if not prompt to login by activating the drop method re-auth..
try{
  phoneHome();
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("not saving accessToken");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Access Information Does Not Exist,\n Please Login"+
"Please Login By Clicking 'OK'"); 
 drop(); // will run auth method for user to login
}



// user picks file to upload with JFileChooser
 fc = new JFileChooser();
 fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
 fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
int dialog = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
 if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

   inputFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
   inputFile.getName();
   inputFile.getAbsoluteFile();
    String nameOf = inputFile.getName();
    System.out.println(" File: " + inputFile);

try{
setTitle("Uploading File..");
/*
// Original needs to look like this before its accepted to dropbox via. upload

File selectedFile = new File(nameOf+inputFile);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

*/
//////////////////////////////////////////////ENCRYPTION NEW
 Cipher cipher = getCipherEncrypt(key);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherOutputStream cos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read = fis.read(data);
            while (read != -1) {
                cos.write(data, 0, read);
                read = fis.read(data);
              System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
            }
            cos.flush();


            File finalFile = new File ("encryptedVersion"+outputFile);
            FileInputStream finalFis = new FileInputStream (finalFile);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////ENCRYPTION NEW    

uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +finalFile ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), fis);

// Original uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +selectedFile ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);

   System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Upload:" + uploadedFile.toString(),
"Success!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);



    }finally{
            cos.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed To Upload File",
"Attention", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 }
}
}
```

** problem that has arisen: how to get the encrypt methods out file to be uploaded into the dropbox

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

```
private byte[] getKeyBytes(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(key.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }

    public Cipher getCipherEncrypt(final byte[] key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
    }

    public void encrypt(File in, File output, byte[] key) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = getCipherEncrypt(key);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        CipherOutputStream cos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(in);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
            cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int read = fis.read(data);
            while (read != -1) {
                cos.write(data, 0, read);
                read = fis.read(data);
               System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());

            }
            cos.flush();
            System.out.println("name"+ output);


        } finally {
            System.out.println("performed encrypt method now closing streams");
            cos.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }




// Working Upload Method To DropBox Cloud
public void uploadFile () throws DbxException, IOException, FileLoadException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidParameterSpecException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException, ShortBufferException, Exception {

// autheticate if there is a accessToken here if not prompt to login by activating the drop method re-auth..
try{
  phoneHome();
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("not saving accessToken");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Access Information Does Not Exist,\n Please Login"+
"Please Login By Clicking 'OK'"); 
 drop(); // will run auth method for user to login
}

// user picks file to upload with JFileChooser
 fc = new JFileChooser();
 fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
 fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
int dialog = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
 if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

   inputFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
   inputFile.getName();
   inputFile.getAbsoluteFile();
    String nameOf = inputFile.getName();
    System.out.println(" File: " + inputFile);


/* calling out inputFIle from out JFileChooser and now passing it into
    our method and encrytping and outputing it.
    */
encrypt(inputFile, new File("Encrypted"),key);

File selected = new File ("Encrypted"+inputFile);
inputStream = new FileInputStream (selected);
uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +selected ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);

/*
File selectedFile = new File(nameOf+inputFile);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

*/


//uploadedFile = client.uploadFile( "/" +selectedFile ,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
setTitle("Uploading File..");
System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Upload:" + uploadedFile.toString(),
        "Success!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Comment: "Null file pointer" has nothing to do with crypto - please post more details of where this is happening.

Comment: This is the error code it is pointing to the closing of the streams 'cos,fos,fis    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at daword.dropBox.uploadFile(dropBox.java:522)
 at daword.dropBox.actionPerformed(dropBox.java:283) I have got rid of the file pointer problem it was s simple fix but this is the problem I was having now and before